# jQuery Bootstrap works in Firefox but not IE

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, firefox

Why does jQuery and Bootstrap work in Firefox but when I open up the same page in IE nothing works??? Ugh can anyone please explain what you must do when this happens? You have to write separate code for each Browser? I don't even know where to begin how can it work in one browser but not the other!?

http://jsfiddle.net/znnm74d5/

This example works in firefox but not IE

```
<select name="SPECIAL" id="SPECIAL">
  <option>Please Select</option>
    <option data-name="Animal Friend" data-img="/images/img/AnimalFriend.png" data-price="$30" value="1">Animal Friend</option>
    <option data-name="Aquaculture" data-img="/images/img/Aquaculture.png" data-price="$30" value="2">Aquaculture</option>
    <option data-name="Protect Our Oceans" data-img="/images/img/ProtectOurOceans.png" data-price="$30" value="3">Protect Our Oceans</option>
    <option data-name="Conserve Wildlife" data-img="/images/img/ConserveWildlife.png" data-price="$30" value="4">Conserve Wildlife</option>
</select>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_special" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Specialty Plate</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary accept">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$(function() {
        $('#SPECIAL').on('change', function() {
            if ($('option:selected', this).is('[data-img]')) {
                $('#modal_special').find('.modal-body').html('<p>Image will go here:</p>')
                .append('<img alt="coming soon" src="' + $('option:selected', this).data('img') + '"/>')
                .end().modal('show');
            }
        });
        $('.accept').on('click',function() {
            //do something
            $('#modal_special').modal('hide');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap and IE?

Comment: You need to post your code. We can't read your mind.

Comment: Try using [Html5Shiv and Respond.js](http://www.joostrap.com/blog/bootstrap-3-supporting-internet-explorer-8-and-9)

Comment: Are you sure you're running IE in edge mode and not quirks mode?

Comment: How 2.0 Changed

Here are some highlights of the changes that jQuery 2.0 brings:

No more support for IE 6/7/8: Remember that this can also affect IE9 and even IE10 if they are used in their “Compatibility View” modes that emulate older versions. To prevent these newer IE versions from slipping back into prehistoric modes, we suggest you always use an X-UA-Compatible tag or HTTP header. If you can use the HTTP header it is slightly better for performance because it avoids a potential browser parser restart. http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

Comment: @Bauer Your markup is invalid. I mean, `<option>Please Select</div>`, seriously?

Answer (score 2):

Bit of an open question without versions of either Bootstrap or IE.

Though its worth noting that the latest Bootstrap build does not support IE7 and below.  Additionally if you want support for IE8/9 then you need to to add additional libraries such as Respond.js

There is a whole section within the Boostrap docs regarding browser support and actions you need to take to get everything running smoothly.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-respondjs

Comment: Does that fix jQuery 2.1 and bootstrap 3.2?

Comment: All I should need is to add a respond? I just have many functions through jQuery that work in firefox and don't even exist in IE10 I didn't think I should display all functions..

Comment: Bootstrap works from jQuery 1.9.0 and up.  jQuery 2.1 does not support IE8 while 1.9 does.  IE10 should be fine across any jQuery and Bootstrap version.  Do you have an specific errors you are getting?

Comment: JQuery docs for 2.x we suggest you always use an X-UA-Compatible tag or HTTP header. Bootstrap demo is 1.11 of jQuery AND the X-UA-... stuff

Comment: I think this may be the problem christina

Comment: IE10 works fine on my computer but many other computers running IE10 on the same network are not being able to run it I think it has something to do with compatability mode or something. Is there a certain tag you can suggest I try using? I am very new to all this

Comment: I am assuming something like this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Comment: nope that did not work

Answer (score 1):

Given the little informatoin you provided in the Question, the most obvious source of the behaviour would be an outdated version of IE (8 or less). (See Browser-Support in the [Bootstrap-docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support))

If so, try to include [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) into your site. If that doen't solve the issue, i would highly recommend that you provide some more information in the question.

Comment: In this case, provide an example (this is possible using Stackoverflow, jsfiddle or bootply for instance)